# Что изменить в программе? Не могу додумать

Tags: c++

Есть класс часы и статический атрибут часовой пояс. Необходимо перевести все часы. Написал программу но она какая-то тривиальная что-ли. Может кто-нибудь что-нибудь подскажет чтобы ее улучшить.

```
  #include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<Windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
using namespace std;
/* ласс "„асы"*/
class Clock {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo;
public:
    static int time_zone; //статический атрибут - часовой по¤с
    // онструктор без параметров
    Clock() 
    {
        time(&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime); //получить текущее системное врем¤
    }
    /*‘ункци¤ вывода времени на экран с учетом часового по¤са*/
    void print_time() {
        if (this->timeinfo->tm_hour + time_zone > 24)
        {
            this->timeinfo->tm_hour = (this->timeinfo->tm_hour + time_zone) - 24;
            cout << this->timeinfo->tm_hour << ":" << this->timeinfo->tm_min << ":" << this->timeinfo->tm_sec << endl;
        }
        else {cout << this->timeinfo->tm_hour + time_zone << ":" << this->timeinfo->tm_min << ":" << this->timeinfo->tm_sec << endl; }
    }
    //статический метод, который измен¤ет значение статического атрибута
    static void modifie(int a)
    {
        time_zone = a;
    }   

};

int Clock::time_zone = 0; //начальна¤ инициализаци¤ статической переменной

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Clock a;
    Sleep(5000); //временна¤ задержка
    Clock b;
    cout << "¬рем¤ є1 (" << Clock::time_zone << "- ый час.по¤с) = ";
    a.print_time();
    cout << "¬рем¤ є2 (" << Clock::time_zone << "- ый час.по¤с) = ";
    b.print_time();
    Clock::modifie(14);
    cout << "¬рем¤ є1 (" << Clock::time_zone << "- ый час.по¤с) = ";
    a.print_time();
    cout << "¬рем¤ є2 (" << Clock::time_zone << "- ый час.по¤с) = ";
    b.print_time();
    system("pause");
```

}

Comment: А почему вас не устраивает, что программа простая? Поставьте себе более сложное задание, вот и программа будет посложнее.

Answer (score 0):

1) использовать локали, т.к. работа с часовыми поясами зависит от региона

2) использовать `UTF-8` для вывода строк, т.к. русский язык

Могу посоветовать библиотеку [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) для обеих проблем.